# Railsのコントローラについて教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails初心者です。
ファットコントローラ問題を解決する方法をネットで調べていましたら、以下のような記事がありました。
https://postd.cc/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/

ここには

```
class Inboxes::PendingsController < ApplicationController
```

というものが紹介されています。
通常のコントローラですと、`rails g controller コントローラ名`で作成しますが
上記のようなコントローラはどのようなコマンドで作成するのでしょうか？

また、上記コントローラの`::`というのは、どのような意味を持つのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`::` は演算子の一種で、「モジュールの中のモジュール」を表現/参照したい時に使います。
ここでは `Inboxes` モジュールの中にある `PendingsController` クラスという意味です。

ジェネレータでの作成方法ですが、 <kbd>rails generate controller</kbd> に何も渡さずに実行すると出るヘルプメッセージの中に、

> To create a controller within a module, specify the controller name as a path like 'parent_module/controller_name'.

とありますね。

Comment: ありがとうございました！助かりました！